# Angular 2/4: Loading sass variables per module

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, sass, angular-cli

We have a core module that defines components, and child modules that inherit the core module (within a single app). Child modules contain child components, which inherit from core components.

Each component in the core module imports variables via a sass import. I want the child components to use different different sass variables, but without having to redefine all the css rules.

**How can I achieve this?**

Note: I've found a solution if each child module is in a separate app. Using  the "stylePreprocessorOptions" config (defined per application) in .angular-cli.json, I'm able to import variables in the core components using the file name instead of the file relative path. That way, each child component uses the right variable files without anything to do. But I do not want to use several apps, as we'll have like 40 of them...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing your existing style in your project

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

Cli handles the rest of it.

When you create each component it has independent scss files right when created using CLI. Can you explain your exact issue may be show the code structure?

Comment: My project is already using sass. I want to be able to change the sass variables for all components in a module, without having to redefine the sass import in all components

Comment: Is the issue with relative paths in imports?

Comment: No, this works if the child modules are in different applications, as I mentionned in my question. In my case, I want all my modules in the same app, so I cannot use that